# Change Serverside OnClientclick to jQuery on client side

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

How can I change this code to jQuery on the client side instead of server side code.
c#

btnUpload.OnClientClick = "javascript:showFileUploader('ctl00_contentMain_pnlUploadCntrlContainer'); return false;";

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('#<%= btnUpload.ClientID %>').click(function(){
       showFileUploader('#<%= pnlUploadCntrlContainer.ClientID %>'); 
       return false;
});
```